# How to extract a value only once in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-functional-component

I am trying to extract a value from a json file only once. Meaning that I don't want it to do the same job once the component get re-rendered. I tried doing it with useEffect() though for some reason the value doesn't get extracted and I get a empty object.

```
import quotes from '../quotes.json'
    function Header () {
        var currentQuote = {}
     
        useEffect(() => {
             currentQuote = quotes.listOfQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.listOfQuotes.length)]
        }, [])
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useMemo` will work. Similarly to `useEffect`, it'll run only when the dependency array changes, so if you pass an empty dependency array, it'll only run on mount.

```
var currentQuote = useMemo(() => (
  quotes.listOfQuotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.listOfQuotes.length)]
), []);
```

Comment: Just curious can the ```setState``` in ```useEffect``` work and why isn't the original code work. Btw, this is a nice way I didn't think of.

Comment: It can, but the component will be rendered for a short time before the effect hook runs, so there might be a slight flash or something on the user's screen. `useLayoutEffect` would fix it by running more quickly, before the screen gets painted. But `useMemo` is even easier I think.

Comment: I got a "'useMemo' is not defined  no-undef" error. Any ideas?

Comment: @aratata You need to import it from React.

Comment: Well that does make sense :D Thank you!

Comment: UseMemo isn't need here. The empty array as deps is like a `componentDidMount` in a class component, triggered only once.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I wonder if the original code doesn't work is because of the data flow in React. If I declare a variable, except using ```setState``` to trigger the render. Otherwise, I cannot get the latest update?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 Yeah, reassigning any variable in React (except a ref's `.current`) is almost always  an antipattern. Best to always use `const`, and to think really hard about other methods if you think you need `let` instead. Variable reassignment alone doesn't cause any side-effects.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  This is definitely a click for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your value in a state if you want it to be rendered in your view. You already give an empty array as deps for the useEffect so it won't be triggered at every rendering. Here is [a Stackblitz repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-4nnvxx) and here is the code :

```
function Header() {
  const [currentQuote, setCurrentQuote] = React.useState('');
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState(0);
  const quotes = {
    listOfQuotes:['lol', 'test', 'another value', 'super quote']
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.listOfQuotes.length) = ', Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.listOfQuotes.length))
    setCurrentQuote(
      quotes.listOfQuotes[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.listOfQuotes.length)
      ]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setVal(3)}>Edit val</button><br />
      {currentQuote}<br />
      {val}
    </>
  )
}
```